# How to use std::less in a vector that contains classes

Tags: c++

How to use std::less in a vector that contains classes, all google results are with plain int examples.

When it comes to classes, for example:

```
class A{
   public:
      A( int value = 0 ):m_value(value){};
      int m_value;
};
```

How to do something like:

`std::count_if( m_cells.begin(), m_cells.end(), std::less< int >() );`

Less will receive an A, not an int. `std::less< A >`

Seems like less needs a functor `operator()()`, how to avoid this? I need to implement operator<( int a ) ? Make a bind? What else?

Code:

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <vector>
  3 #include <algorithm>
  4
  5 using namespace std;
  6
  7 class A
  8 {
  9    public:
 10       A(int a = 0 ):m_value(a) {}
 11       bool operator!=( int a )
 12       {
 13          return m_value != a;
 14       }
 15
 16       bool operator<( A &a )
 17       {
 18          return m_value < a.m_value;
 19       }
 20
 21       int m_value;
 22 };
 23
 24
 25 int main(){
 26    std::vector< A > m_cells( 5 );
 27
 28    m_cells[2].m_value = 3;
 29    m_cells[3].m_value = 4;
 30    m_cells[4].m_value = 4;
 31    std::count_if( m_cells.begin(), m_cells.end(), std::less< A >() );
 32    return 0;
 33 }
 34
```

This results in:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4437: error: no match for call to ‘(std::less<A>) (A&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_function.h:229: note: candidates are: bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = A]
```

Comment: Three answers and they all recommend operator< as a member function. I thought operator< should be a global function, isn't that recognised best practise?

Comment: @john I only see two which recommend `operator<`; unless you can provide a `operator<` which has expected semantics for `A`, you shouldn't; use something else instead.  (And if you do provide `operator<`, you should provide the other 5 comparison operators as well.)  As for member or not: given that `A` has an implicit conversion from `int`, `operator<` probably should be a global function.  Without any implicit conversions to the type, however, it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement an `operator<` for `A`, and then pass in `std::less<A>`, other options (for example you could implement a conversion operator to `int` - YUCKYUCKYUCKYUCK)

EDIT: To continue...

Like James says, `std::less<>` requires two arguments, if you are stuck on c++03 (and don't have boost), you can do something like the following:

```
std::count_if( m_cells.begin(), m_cells.end() ,std::bind1st(std::less<A>(), 3) )
```

Basically one of the arguments is bound to `3` - this the first argument (consider the left hand side), you can also bind to the second argument (right hand side - using `std::bind2nd`), depending on how you want the predicate to work.

This approach requires that you properly implement `operator<`, i.e.

```
bool operator<(A const& a) const
{
}
```

EDIT2: for c++11, you can try any of the following:

```
 std::cout << std::count_if( m_cells.begin(), m_cells.end() , [](A const& a) { return 3 < a.m_value; } ) << std::endl; // lambda
 std::cout << std::count_if( m_cells.begin(), m_cells.end() , std::bind(std::less<A>(), _1, 4) ) << std::endl; // bind second argument (rhs)
 std::cout << std::count_if( m_cells.begin(), m_cells.end() , std::bind(std::less<A>(), 3, _1) ) << std::endl; // bind first argument (lhs)
```

Comment: my code is close of what you said, but it results in:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4437: error: no match for call to ‘(std::less<A>) (A&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_function.h:229: note: candidates are: bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = A]

Comment: you need to change the signature to `bool operator<(A const& a)`, note the `const` reference.

Comment: That won't solve anything (and may be misleading).  `std::less` requires two arguments, `std::count_if` only provides one.

Comment: Very similar error: no match for call to ‘(std::less<A>) (A&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_function.h:229: note: candidates are: bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = A]

Comment: @JamesKanze doesn't count_if receives the value from less? I think that less is processed very before count_if 'cause count_if calls less and wait for it to do  a ++at some var.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I was only talking about how `operator<` should be implemented, now edited to account for the `std::count_if`

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel The instance of `less` is constructed before `count_if` is called.  But its `operator()()` takes two arguments, not one; `less` returns true if the first argument is less than the second.

Answer (score 2):

You need more than just `std::less`, even if it were a vector of `int`.
`std::count_if` calls the predicate with a single argument; `std::less`
requires two.

There are a number of other functional objects, along the lines of
`std::bind2nd` which can be combined.  Figuring out the correct
combination isn't trivial, however, and the results are both unreadable
and fragile, so it's not a solution I'd recommend.  If you're using
C++11, there's lamba, which is clearly the way to go.  Otherwise,
boost::bind is quite usable; if you can't use Boost, about the only
reasonable solution is to write a predicate object of your own,
something like:

```
class ALessThan
{
    int myUpperLimit;
public:
    ALessThan( int upperLimit ) : myUpperLimit( upperLimit ) {}
    bool operator()( A const& object ) const
    {
        return object.m_value < myUpperLimit;
    }
};
```

(Note that no matter how you do it, you're going to have to provide an
argument to the predicate.  Less than what?)

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel Not having access to a C++11 compiler at the moment, so that I can test it, no.  (And I haven't used C++11 enough to be sure that something I haven't tested is even roughly right.)  But the `lambda` example that Nim gives looks about what I would expect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your definition of `operator<` that `std::less<>` uses under the hood.

With your current `operator<`, you are effectively telling the compiler that the operator might change either of its operands (as neither the operator nor its argument are declared `const`).
As `std::less<>` doesn't want the operands of `operator<` to change, your implementation is not acceptable.

To fix it, change the definition of `operator<` to:

```
16       bool operator<( const A &a ) const
17       {
18          return m_value < a.m_value;
19       }
```

(Note the addition of `const` on line 16). This tells the compiler that your `operator<` won't change either of its operands, making it acceptable for use by `std::less<>`.